# Reveal whole truncated text on hover in grid - is there a better solution?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items (each item has a grid layout), but sometimes the content of the "cell" does not fit the predefined width.

I would like to show the whole text over the other fields when it is hovered over with the mouse.

[Here is a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oatf0e4y/36/)

```css
#list{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 5em auto 3em 3em;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.entry > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.entry-text {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.entry > *:hover:not(.entry-id) {
  position: absolute; /* I would like to avoid this */
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 2em; /* I don't want this hardcoded */
}
```

```html
<div id='list'>
  <div class='entry'>
    <div class='entry-id'>1</div>
    <div class='entry-type'>short text</div>
    <div class='entry-text'>this is a text description that can be long</div>
    <div class='entry-field'>now</div>
    <div class='entry-time'>9:12</div>
  </div>
  <div class='entry'>
    <div class='entry-id'>2</div>
    <div class='entry-type'>very long text that won't fit the cell</div>
    <div class='entry-text'>this is another text description that can be long</div>
    <div class='entry-field'>what about</div>
    <div class='entry-time'>10:24</div>
  </div>
  <div class='entry'>
    <div class='entry-id'>3</div>
    <div class='entry-type'>long text but shorter</div>
    <div class='entry-text'>this is yetanother text description that also can be long</div>
    <div class='entry-field'>this</div>
    <div class='entry-time'>11:09</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I sort of managed to do what I wanted the end result to look like, but it only works properly on the first column. If I wanted it to work for all columns, I would have to duplicate a lot of code and then it would not work for any other layout. Also, since there is a column that is set to `auto`, I have no idea how to absolutely position the items after that if I were to resort to the unclean solution.

It would be also jolly if there was a way to only apply the selector on the rows where the text actually overflows so it does not highlight everything, but I believe that's not possible without JS.

I'm aware that there are similar questions with answers already, but none satisfies my needs. Thanks to anyone who tries to help me :)

Comment: What about using a Tooltip? That way it won't break the layout since the Tooltips often are positioned

Comment: @konekoya I thought about it, but tooltips do not work on mobile :(

Comment: in entry > *:hover:not(.entry-id)  change position to fixed. it will be ok for you??

Comment: @MehediHasanSiam absolutely not :( Not only it does not change anything, but it fixes the element on the page so scrolling won't work. (Assume the list is very long)